# How to get response of url in window.open() method in the same page where window.open() method is fired?

Tags: window.opener

How to get response of url in window.open() method in the same page where window.open() method is fired?

```
var w1 = window.open("givenurl",'_blank', 
'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes, function(res){
    console.log("w1: " + res);
});
```